# Modification of derivation

Tags: derivatives

Could you explain me how to modify: $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-7\sin(4x)\ln(x)}\right)$$ to this form: $$7x^{7sin(4x)} \cdot \left(4\cos(4x)\ln(x)+\frac{\sin(4x)}{x}\right).$$ Thank you :).

I apologize for the registration example. Next time I will try to write it correctly. Thank you for understanding

Comment: The chain rule in this case says that the required derivative is equals to $$e^{-7\sin 4x \ln x}\frac{d}{dx}\left(-7\sin 4x \ln x\right)$$ Try working this out.

Answer (score 0):

First note that: $$e^{-7\sin(4x)\ln(x)}=\left(e^{\ln(x)}\right)^{-7\sin(4x)}=x^{-7\sin(4x)}.$$

By the chain rule and product rule, we have: 
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-7\sin(4x)\ln(x)}\right)&=\left(-7\cos(4x)\ln(x)-\frac{7\sin(4x)}{x}\right)e^{-7\sin(4x)\ln(x)} \\
&=-7x^{-7\sin(4x)}\cdot\left(\cos(4x)\ln(x)+\frac{\sin(4x)}{x}\right).
\end{align}

(I think you are missing a minus sign in your question.)